# Using iPhone 4s UIImageView on iPhone 6PLUS in Auto Layout

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, autolayout

So just to test Auto Layout, I put in a full screen iPhone 4s size UIImageView. Then with Auto Layout that iPhone 4s UImageView on full screen became iPhone 6PLUS fullscreen UIImageView.

I played UIImageView on both simulators and I can't tell whether Auto Layout just stretches the iPhone 4s Image to iPhone 6Plus size or does Auto Layout iPhone 6Plus image make it into a retina resolution image by itself?

Or is it best to first make an image that fits iPhone 6PLUS and then use Auto Layout to make it on the smaller phone sizes.

Which way would make a better visual quality image on all phones?

Comment: It stretches the image that is loaded into the ImageView. Whether it uses a retina image depends on how you obtained that image. If you did that with the normal `imagenamed:` call, then it will automatically load the (triple-)retina version for 6+.

Comment: Don't repost your questions. Instead, update the original if you have more details to provide.

Comment: rmaddy, those are 2 different questions. The one you linked to asks how to change image sizes for different devices in Auto Layout. While this question asks if it's better to make an image for iPhone 6PLUS size and then scale down or better to make image for iPhone 4s and then scale up using Auto Layout.